# How to plot magnitude response using $\tt freqz$ in MATLAB if I have a transfer function without a denominator

Tags: matlab, homework, transfer-function

So I have the transfer function:

$$H[z] = 1 + \sqrt{2}z^{-1} + z^{-2} $$

And I have to evaluate $H(e^{j\omega})$ for $\omega= 0, \pi/4, \pi/4 \ldots$

I have done the calculations manually using Euler's formula, but now the assignment is asking me to compare these plots with the plots using `freqz` in MATLAB. I can't seem to find instructions on how I can do that with this type of transfer function.

Comment: I can't even :D So, hint: any number is $x$ is representable by $\frac xy$ for a specific number $y$. Always. What's that $y$?

Comment: From what I can see, you have the numerator (`b`) of your filter. So simply plug it to `freqz` and voila.

Answer (score 2):

You simply specify `a = 1` (because the denominator equals $1$). So you get

```
b = [1,sqrt(2),1];
a = 1;
N = 512;
[H,w] = freqz(b,a,N);
```

You can compare this to the analytical solution:

```
H2 = 1 + sqrt(2)*exp(-1i*w) + exp(-1i*2*w);
max(abs(H2-H))    % 8.0825e-16
```

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to this, but what is N representing here?

Comment: @Freddie: It's the number of (equidistant) frequency points at which the frequency response is evaluated. Just check out the [Matlab documentation of `freqz`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html).

Answer (score 0):

For the evaluation only at specific frequencies, you need to specify the frequency vector with at least two frequencies in it (see [MATLAB's freqz](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html)). Below is the MATLAB code for the evaluation at the frequencies $\omega = 0, \pi/4, \pi/2, 3\pi/4, \text{and}\ \pi$.

```
>> [h, w] = freqz([1, sqrt(2), 1], 1, [0 , pi/4, pi/2, 3*pi/4 pi])

h =

   3.4142 + 0.0000i   2.0000 - 2.0000i   0.0000 - 1.4142i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i   0.5858 + 0.0000i


w =

         0    0.7854    1.5708    2.3562    3.1416

>>
```

For the visualization of the results above, see the magnitude response, i.e. $20\log_{10}\left(\lvert H\left(\omega\right)\rvert\right)$, plotted below with the five frequencies marked in red.

[image]

Note that for $\pm 3\pi/4$ you have that (see code results above)
$$
H\left(\pm \frac{3\pi}{4}\right) = 0\implies
20\log_{10}\left(\bigg\lvert H\left(\pm \frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\bigg\rvert\right) = -\infty
$$
Also from the fact that the zeros are at
$$
z = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\pm j\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\quad\text{with}\quad z = e^{j\omega}
$$
The corresponding magnitude for $\omega = 3\pi/4$ is not shown on the single-sided magnitude response plot above but you can see the asymptotic trend at $3\pi/4$.